# Imprimindo listas

Tags: python, lista

alguem poderia explicar porque a lista do seguinte código não é impressa?
Valeu!

```
def produtos_pedidos(produtos):
    lista = []
    while True:
        pedido = input("Qual produto você quer pedir? Para encerrar o pedido digite 0: ")
        if pedido in produtos:
            quantidade = input("Qual a quantidade de {}? ".format(pedido))
            total = print("Você pediu {} {}. ".format (quantidade, pedido))
            lista.append(total)
        elif pedido == "0":
            print("Seu pedido foi encerrado")
            return lista
        else:
            input("Não temos esse produto. Para ver o cardápio digite C: ").upper()
            print(produtos)
```

Comment: Por que ter um parâmetro `pedido` se ele é sobrescrito logo na primeira linha do loop? O mesmo vale para o parâmetro `quantidade`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua lista está sendo retornada para a função principal, e não printada, assim no código  principal você deve ter algo do tipo:

```
sua_lista = produtos_pedidos(produtos, pedido, quantidade)
```

Então a lista que estava apenas dentro da função, vai ser repassada para o código principal. Se você deseja apenas mostrar a lista na tela, e não pretende usar no restante do código, substitua o `return lista` por um `print(lista)`.

Edit:

Você está passando para a variável `total` o retorno do `print`, porém essa função não retorna. Se na sua lista você quer armazenar o produto e a quantidade que foi pedida, você deve fazer algo assim dentro daquele primeiro if:

```
quantidade = input("Qual a quantidade de {}? ".format(pedido))
print("Você pediu {} {}. ".format (quantidade, pedido))
lista.append([pedido,quantidade])
```

Você nem precisa da variável `total` basta passar os valores diretamente para a lista.

Comment: com o print(lista) ele nao mostra valor nenhum

Comment: Agora que eu percebi uma coisa, seu total recebe o print, porém a função print não retorna nada para armazenar na variável total, e é exatamente o total que você passa para a lista. O que exatamente deveria haver nessa lista? Um valor? Um par com o nome do produto e a quantidade? De qualquer forma você precisa passar os valores desejados para a variável total (ou colocá-los diretamente na lista) e fazer o print("você pediu....), separado, sem atribuir a uma variável.

Comment: Fiz um edit na minha resposta, talvez agora funcione.

Comment: Muito obrigada. Não sabia que podia colocar mais de um argumento no .append
Boa explicação, a sua :)

Comment: Mas esse append só tem 1 argumento, uma lista, e dentro dessa lista tem dois valores. Note que dessa forma você vai passar várias listas pra dentro da variável 'lista' , cada uma dessas listas menores, vai ter um par, contendo o produto e a quantidade do pedido.

Comment: eita. ok. Vou continuar estudando.

Comment: Note também que, conforme o Augusto Vasques sugeriu no comentário dele, você não precisa passar 'pedido' e 'quantidade' como parâmetros da função, pois você não utiliza esses valores passados, você pede diretamente dentro da função. O único parâmetro que você precisa é o 'produtos'.

Answer (score 2):

Ao invés de `return lista`, coloca `print(lista)`.

O `return` retorna o valor para uma outra variável e não imprime o resultado na tela.